# Alignment of option text of select2 element

Tags: jquery, dropdown, jquery-select2

Hi I have a dropdwon select2 element having options

```
<div id=method  class="form-group">
    <select id="selectNumber3" class="form-control selectCustom" style="width: 300px">
        <!-- <option value="Variable Selection Method">Variable Selection Method</option> -->
        <!-- <option value="Network_graph">Frequency Method</option> -->
        <!-- <option value="CF">Counter Factual Method</option> -->
        <!-- <option value="ML">ML Method</option> -->
    </select>
</div>
```

CSS:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqtBZ.png)

When i am rendering this select2 element it's not coming in a proper alignment

Please find below the screenshot, the options are going out of the screen. I want this dropdown to be left aligned.

Thanks in advance !!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4a5I3.png)

Comment: You will have to inspect those `<option>` to find what CSS is in cause. No one can tell with just the HTML.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Thanks for the prompt response 
i have inspected the options element and attached the screenshot as well..

Comment: It sadly isn't instructive. You have to look for something that would move the elements to the left. Something like a negative `margin-left` or `left` or a `transform: translateX(-10px)`... things like that.